# .htaccess 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is causing a 500 error with the below code in the .htaccess file?

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.shtml /$1.php
RewriteRule ^Marketing-Resources/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.shtml /Marketing-Resources/$1.php
RewriteRule ^Affiliates/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.shtml /Affiliates/$1.php
RewriteRule ^Help/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.shtml /Help/$1.php
RewriteRule ^Specialty-Lists/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)\.shtml /Specialty-Lists/$1.php
```

If it matters the file is inside the folder of a subdomain.

Comment: Do you have access to the web server's error log? It will always contain information about every 500 that gets thrown.

Comment: @Pekka..... djn pointed out my silly mistake. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

These two lines usually belong to robots.txt, not .htaccess...

Comment: .oO(cargo cult web server administration)

Comment: lmao...... good catch. I just added those, can't believe I put them in there instead of robots haha. Thanks!

Comment: This one was devious. I had to look twice to notice them.